# Convert base64 image stream to image file but blank

Tags: php, base64

First of all, here is my code:

```
<?php
$img_stream = "iVBORw0K...2Fm6vOQECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECUWA%2B%2B511gm293QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D"; // Too long
//echo "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,".$img_stream."\" />";
$img_stream = str_replace(' ', '+', $img_stream);
$filename = md5(time()) . random_int(1000, 9999) . '.png';
$fhandle = fopen($filename, 'wb');
$body = base64_decode($img_stream);
fwrite($fhandle, $body);
fclose($fhandle);
echo "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,".$img_stream."\" />";
?>
```

I am new to base64 image stream. That code works on my machine, which means I can   see the pictures. But the image file is always blank. I tried something like

```
$img_stream= str_replace(' ', '+', $img_stream);
```

but still not working.
Anyone knows which part goes wrong?

Comment: is your `error_log` logging anything?

Comment: Seems just some warning? I cleared it and try once. Still the page shows the picture but a blank image file in my root directory.

Comment: "some" warning? you should pay attention to every notice and warning, and put checks in place to stop them from happening. What did the warning say?

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:35.658897 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 2376:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:35.837966 2018] [core:warn] [pid 2376:tid 640] AH00098: pid file C:/Users/luoru/hidden/xampp70/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:36.109336 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 2376:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:38.224667 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2376:tid 640] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/7.0.30 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:38.224667 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2376:tid 640] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Mar 29 2018 11:38:15

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:38.224667 2018] [core:notice] [pid 2376:tid 640] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\users\\luoru\\hidden\\xampp70\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Users/luoru/hidden/xampp70/apache'

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:38.230240 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2376:tid 640] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 12328

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:39.879439 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 12328:tid 680] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:40.239396 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 12328:tid 680] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: [Thu Jun 21 17:53:40.317519 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12328:tid 680] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: That's your apache log, not your PHP log.